# How do I find the point on a paraboloid that is nearest to a given vertex?

Tags: polynomials, optimization, surfaces

Given a vertex with coordinates $\mathbf{x}_0\!=\!(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, I'd like to compute the coordinates of the nearest point to $\mathbf{x}_0$ on the paraboloid whose equation is

\begin{align}
z = P(x,y) = c_0 + c_1x + c_2y + c_3xy + c_4x^2 + c_5y^2
\end{align}

How do I analytically minimise the squared-distance from the point to the surface? I'd prefer to not solve this numerically.

Comment: Hi, welcome.  You tagged this as `optimization`, which is a clue.  What quantity is optimized by the **nearest** point to a surface?

Comment: @hardmath Actually in this case, $z=P(x,y)$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thanks. In face my question is actually...how do I minimise the resulting expression for the distance/distance-squared?

Comment: @hardmath: Are you sure? Doesn't that require the paraboloid to be radially symmetric?

Comment: Why do you call a given point a vertex? Vertex of what?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Symantics. What's important is that $\mathbf{x}_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Perhaps you need to consider to minimize 
$$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2 +z-z_0)^2,$$
subject to 
$$c_1x + c_2y + c_3xy + c_4x^2 + c_5y^2-z=-c_0.$$

For, ones takes the gradient of both relations and makes them proportional, that is
$$[2(x-x_0),2(y-y_0),2(z-z_0)]=\lambda [c_1+c_3y+2c_4x,c_2+c_3x+2c_5y,-1]$$
from which you get three equations
$$2(x-x_0)=\lambda (c_1+c_3y+2c_4x),$$
$$2(y-y_0)=\lambda (c_2+c_3x+2c_5y),$$
$$2(z-z_0)=-\lambda.$$

Now a strategy is to solve for $\lambda$ in each and from this, the resulting relations, will determine how $x,y,z$ dependent among them.

If this isn't enough to go through let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response! So I'm seeing 3 equations and 4 unknowns (incl. $\lambda$). So how would you go about solving for $\lambda$?

Comment: Don't solve for $\lambda$. Eliminate it and get two equations (plus your original) in $x,y,z$.

Comment: @niran90: you will have $$\lambda=\frac{2(x-x_0)}{c_1+c_3y+2c_4x}=\frac{2(y-y_0)}{c_2+c_3x+2c_5y}=-2(z-z_0)$$

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh I see. And how would I solve the resulting set of non-linear equations?

Comment: Do you have particular values for all the $c_i$? Even so, you're going to end up with a cubic equations in $x$ and $y$, so the general case will be basically impossible. By the way, depending on the values of $c_3$, $c_4$, and $c_5$, this may not be a typical (upward- or downward-pointing) paraboloid; it may be a saddle surface. Indeed, when I plug this into Mathematica, it ends up with quintic equations to solve for $x$ and $y$, so it is pretty much pointless to try this.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to find the nearest point on the paraboloid:

1) Calculate the normal vector to the paraboloid at the point $(x,y,z)$
$$\vec{n} = (z_x', z_y', -1) = (c_1+c_3y+2c_4x,\> c_2+c_3x+2c_5y,\>-1)\tag  1$$

2) The nearest point on the paraboloid is on the line parallel to $\vec{n}$ and passing through $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. The equation of the line is parametrized as $(x_0,y_0,z_0)+t\vec{n}$, or,

$$x=x_0+t(c_1+c_3y+2c_4x)$$
$$y=y_0+t(c_2+c_3x+2c_5y)$$
$$z=z_0-t$$

3) Then, the nearest point is just the intersection between the line and the paraboloid. Solve for $t$ from the system of the equations of the line and the paraboloid.

4) Plug the solution of $t$ into the line equations above to obtain the nearest point coordinates $(x_n,y_n,z_n)$.

Comment: Thanks so much! You presented your solution so elegantly!

Comment: @niran90 - You are welcome. Glad you could visualize and follow the steps.

Comment: Oops. This is incorrect. You're using $x$ to mean both the coordinate of a point on the surface and the coordinate of a point on the line. These are different variables. Same for $y$ and $z$.

Comment: It is okay. Before the final point is solved, it is arbitrary and not fixed, constrained by the surface.

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about. You're using $x$ and $y$ to mean two different things in the same equations.

Comment: @Quanto I agree, I am now slightly confused. In the 3 equations in the middle of your post, $x$ and $y$ feature on both sides of the equations. Doesn't this result in a non-linear system? Can you elaborate on how to solve this system?

Comment: @niran90 - The three equations are a system of linear equations in $x$, $y$ and $z$, which can be solved in terms of the parametrization variable $t$. Then, you plug $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ into the conic equation and solve for $t$. It'd be helpful if apply it to a specific setting to see how it works out.

Comment: Note that the resulting equation for $t$ is nonlinear as you may have noticed. It is expected since solutions may also include the furthest point as well. If the point lies along the axis of the paraboloid, the solution is not just a point, but a circle. The comments made by others may have caused confusion. If one does not feel comfortable to use $(x,y,z)$ for a general point, just replace it with, say, $(p,q,r)$ in the equation.